# Android: Tabbed App with Navigation Stacks

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments

I'm working to clone an iOS app that uses a `UITabBarViewController` as the "main/outer/root" `UIViewController`. Each of its tabs has a `UINavigationController` as the root to manage a navigation stack of `UIViewController` instances.

I am trying very hard to do 2 things:

1. Replicate the functionality of the iOS app.
2. Do so in true "Android" fashion (i.e., not forcing an iOS paradigm in a non-iOS world).

I've searched around a good bit, but this topic seems to have been changed a lot over the past few years. I tried a solution that had a single Activity that managed everything, but that required maintaining separate back stacks, and seemed to get a thumbs down from most users around here.

Currently, I have a solution that is "sort of" working. As I understand it, my current setup is:

- A single, `BaseActivity` class that extends `ActionBarActivity`.
- All activities in my app (only 2 thus far, but slated for 5) extend this class.
- This base activity loads a `drawer.xml` layout, which has an `android:support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` as its outermost item.
- Inside of this is:

  - A `FrameLayout`, which is the container for my fragments.
  - A `ListView`, which is the drawer itself.

Based on my testing of the app, this setup gets me most of what I want.

- When I "navigate" (using the drawer) to a different activity, the correct activity is loaded.
- When I "navigate" to a "deeper" fragment (via on-screen controls), the correct new fragment is pushed and I've overridden `onBackPressed()` in `BaseActivity` to correctly pop the back stack if appropriate.

The problem I'm encountering is this:

1. The app is launched and "Activity 1:Fragment 1" is displayed. I click on an item to move to "Activity 1:Fragment 2" (which works well).
2. I use the drawer to launch Activity 2, and "Activity 2:Fragment 1" is shown. So far, so good.
3. I use the drawer to go **return to** (at least that's my intention) to the existing Activity 1, and "Activity 1:Fragment 1" is displayed.

I've looked into Activity/Intent launch flags, but I'm not sure I really get what's going on. So far, my reading has led me to try the following steps:

1. When switching Activites, setting its flag like this:
   `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);`
2. In my AndroidManifest.xml, setting Activity launchMode like this:
   `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`, or like this 
   `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

An odd, additional problem I'm facing is that launching a new Activity doesn't seem to create the Activity back stack like I expect. When I move from Activity 1 to Activity 2 (ignoring the lack of fragment back stack maintenance for a moment), pressing the back button from Activity 2 closes the app, which confuses me.

Is there a single, **current** best practice for this type of app structure/navigation?

Comment: "I use the drawer to go back" -- what do you mean by this? Items in a navigation drawer are supposed to go to a specific place (e.g., "Contacts"), not to a logical place (e.g., "back to wherever you were before"). "Is there a single, current best practice for this type of app structure/navigation?" -- bear in mind that only a subset of people here will have any idea what your iOS structure/navigation is, as not everybody here is an iOS developer.

Comment: @CommonsWare "Back" as in "return to" not "back" as in "up the navigation stack". Also, I felt like I explained the structure pretty well. It's a set of sibling tabs, each of which maintains its own navigation stack, which should be maintained when returning to that tab.

Comment: "It's a set of sibling tabs, each of which maintains its own navigation stack" -- tabs are not generally used as you describe in Android.

Comment: Can you suggest a replacement paradigm? I'm porting an iOS app. It has 5 distinct sections, each of which have navigation stacks. What's the appropriate idiom to represent that in Android? I looked at the Facebook app, and they have an icon-based bar at the top of the screen that you can tap on or swipe. But if I read a story (so, navigation 1 level deeper in the "News Feed" "tab"), I have to go **back** to the "root" screen in order to switch to my notifications. That seems user-un-friendly to me, but is that the way it's done on Android?

Comment: Your approach of converting those tabs into navigation drawer entries seems perfectly reasonable, outside of the "each of which have navigation stacks" concept. That's not a typical pattern in Android, outside of Web browsers.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, I realize we're out of the scope of the question and into more philosophical issues, but isn't it irritating to Android users to have to restart a logical chain of actions just because they switched tabs? We have a news feed tab (in which you can load news stories) and a messaging tab. I can see a user reading a story and receiving a message. If they hop to the messages tab to answer and then back to the news feed tab, it seems poor form to me to **not** put them back into the story they were reading. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Personally, I expect the BACK button to take me back to where I was in the flow of news, whereas the navigation drawer entry would take me back to the top of the news.

Comment: I need a picture of what your trying to do.  I got lost after the fist ios whatevers

Answer (score 0):

the good approach is to have 1 activity and handle the back stacks manually as Android has only 1 stack. I've done this several times and finally I created a library called Tab Stacker that does the job: a fragment history for each tab.

It is open source and fully documented, and can be included easily with gradle. You can find the library on github: https://github.com/smart-fun/TabStacker

You can also download the sample app to see that the behaviour corresponds to your needs:

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/fr.arnaudguyon.tabstackerapp

If you have any question don't hesitate to drop a mail.